# As a wireless client is the regulatory domain relevant?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, standardisation

If I have a device which acts only as a wireless client, do I have to set and abide a regulatory domain? Is this related only to the scanning process, or when else would this matter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Wi-Fi is a bidirectional layer-1/2 protocol, and every Wi-Fi device must both transmit and receive. It is not like a regular radio or television receiver that passively receives a signal.